# Why my Fourier coefficients are all zeros?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

given a function $f(x) = \frac{\pi -x}{2}$ on $(0,2\pi)$

then

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (\pi-x) cos(nx) dx = \frac{1}{2n\pi} \Big[\pi sin(nx) -\frac{1}{n}\Big(nxsin(nx) + cos(nx) \Big)\Big]_0^{2\pi}=0$$
$$b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (\pi-x) sin(nx) dx = \frac{1}{2 n \pi} \Big[ -\pi cos(nx)-\frac{1}{n} \Big(-nxcos(nx)+sin(nx)\Big) \Big]_0^{2\pi}= 0$$

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you evaluate integrals incorrectly.

Comment: thanks, i edit my closed form solution for clarification. can you provide a bit more details? p/s: just added

Comment: I don't see why $b_n=0$?

Comment: when i tried to double-check by mathematica, it said the same but i can't still see why. the integral is evaluated from $0:2\pi$, perhaps i'm making mistakes at the term $nx cos(nx)$?

Comment: What is $x\cos(nx)$ when $x=2\pi$?  When $x=0$?

Comment: $2\pi cos(2\pi n)$ and 0, yes? isn't it true that as $n=1,2,\cdots$, then $cos(2\pi n) =1$?

Comment: So what is $[nx\cos(nx)]^{2\pi}_0$?

Comment: i know where i'm wrong. thanks both of you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more detailed integration with limits plugged in. Note that $\sin(0) = \sin(2\pi n) = 0$ and $\cos(2\pi n) = 1$.
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^{2\pi} (\pi-x) \sin(n x) dx
  &= \left.-\frac{\sin(n x)+n (\pi-x) \cos(n x)}{n^2} \right|_0^{2\pi} \\
  &= \left.\frac{\sin(n x)+n (\pi-x) \cos(n x)}{n^2} \right|_{2\pi}^0 \\
  &= \frac{n \pi}{n^2} - \frac{-n \pi}{n^2}
   = \frac{2\pi n}{n^2}
   = \frac{2\pi}{n}.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: can you provide a little more step-by-step, especially when limits are plugged in? i'm lost there

Comment: @kensaii see the revamped update

Answer (score 0):

$b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n} [xcos(nx)]_0^{2\pi} = \frac{1}{n}$